# Correct/best way to use a third-party lib in React?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I'm working on a React project and the structure of components is:

```
          Index
            /\
           /  \
ModContainer  MapContainer
      |              /\
[Modules]           /  \
                   Map  Toolbar
```

`Map` contains an OpenLayers map object and I want `Modules` (forms) to interact with it.

Should I pass the map object (instance of OpenLayers.Map) to the Modules as a prop?

Or

Create states and functions inside the Index component (common parent) and pass the functions to Modules as props??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lift the common state up. Create a new container component or just put the state on your root component

Comment: I don't really like the idea of putting everything inside the root comp. I'll need functions that find and highlight polygons in the map, draw lines, etc. How can I translate that to states???

Comment: That can be localized to the Map component (or its container) and you can mantain state needed by your Modules inside a container up in the hierarchy. i.e. you could put the currently painted polygons/pixels in the MapContainer state and whatever you need to know from the Map on the Modules you put it in a Component that contains MapContainer and ModulesContainer

Comment: I get the idea, mostly. In fact, I need the opposite way of data: make the modules trigger a change in the map state by passing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you define as `[Modules]` and what you are asking for but I had some fun actually

```
          _ _ _ _Redux_ _ _ _ _
         /         |           \
        /        Index          \
     _ /           /\            \ _
   /    \         /  \           /   \
  |    ModContainer  MapContainer     |
  |        |              /\          |
   \ _ [Modules]         /  \        /
    \ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ Map  Toolbar _/
```

Comment: Modules is an array of components that render multiple forms on demand for loading data to the server.

Comment: So you need to handle the state of the map object in a common parent, `Index` here, or use a HOC like Redux to handle a global app state to facilitate the communication between these components.

Comment: Unfortunately, my deadlines don't allow me to learn Redux now.. look at my answer above please..

Comment: You could merge ModContainer and MapContainer to handle the state here but that's too abstract to decide what's the best and fastest way to do in your case.

Comment: Ok.. so, in conclusion, you say I have to use states instead of passing the map object to the Modules.

Comment: "Instead of" ? How do you plan to pass the map object to the Modules ? All this discussion is about this.

Comment: The Map _component_ has a property named 'map' which is an instance of the OpenLayer.Map class: the **map object**. I can use refs to catch the Map _component_ and pass its property map to the modules as a prop.

Comment: Using states, I'd pass them as props to the Map _component_ and check them inside `componentWillReceiveProps` and manage the map _object_ inside the _component_. Use case: https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers/blob/master/src/map.tsx#L80

Comment: Yes, btw if you can avoid using ref you should, if you just have the map prop to pass between these components it can be easy to do, your index component will not be complex, it'll just have a method to update the map state that'll be called by his children, and just pass it as a prop in render.